# How do I parse "220510" so the value comes out as 22-05-10?

Tags: c#

When I try this code:

```
string value = "220510"; // The `value` variable is always in this format
string key = "30";
string title;

switch (key)
{
    case "30":
        title = "Date: ";
        Console.WriteLine($"{title} is {value}");
        break;
}
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to insert the '-' character to separate the month, day and year because I want it to display:

`Date:  is 22-05-10`

Please show me how to parse it.

Comment: Your code does not compile, consider editing your question and adding a [mcve]

Comment: Is that just a random piece of code? I'm not sure how that code relates to the question you're asking.

Comment: Why can't you just split your string in to blocks of 2 characters and then insert `-` between them?

Comment: Do you have a `DateTime` object or the string "220510"?

Comment: Assuming `value` is a `string`, `$"{value[0..2]}-{value[2..4]}-{value[4..6]}"`. While you can do this by round-tripping through `DateTime`, this seems unnecessary and error-prone if you ultimately don't need a `DateTime` (and if you do, the two-digit year is a concern). If `value` is `object` or suchlike and the real value is actually an `int` (impossible to tell from here), things become more interesting.

Comment: Your question seems to be: _How do I parse the string 220510 date format so the value comes out as 22-05-10?_  To improve your post, change the name to **that** and post the code _here's what I've tried._ And if that's _not_ what your asking, well, there's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DateTime` object:

```
 oDate.toString("yy-MM-dd");
```

If you have a string you can either:

```
 sDate = sDate.Insert(2,"-");
 sDate = sDate.Insert(5,"-");
```

or go through `DateTime` again (for whatever reason):

```
string sDate = "220510";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime sDate = Convert.ParseExact(iDate, "yyMMdd", provider);

sDate.toString("yy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: **How do I parse the string `220510` date format so the value comes out as 22-05-10?**

In this specific case, consider using the `string.Substring` method to pick out the digit pairs then use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to put them back together.

```
const string raw = "220510";

// To do a simple parse (not using a DateTime object)
var yearString = raw.Substring(0, 2);
var monthString = raw.Substring(2, 2);
var dayString = raw.Substring(4, 2);

var string_22_05_10 = $"{yearString}-{monthString}-{dayString}";
Console.WriteLine(string_22_05_10);
```

[image]